# Openedx Sometimes throws Internal Server error while calling “api/courseware/sequence” api

Tags: django, docker, api, openedx, edx

we have installed openedx with tutor and we are making one edu-tech platform where it is using openedx apis and maintaining its own database at the same time on another django-project in docker.

our edu-tech django-project docker is communicating with openedx apis, and sometimes openedx returns 500 Internal Error while i calling **/api/courseware/sequence/{{block_key}}** api.
then i traced the exception from tutor local lms logs,
this is exception made by openedx-lms.

**NOTE: It happens only sometimes**

```
lms_1                        | 2023-01-02 18:32:42,511 ERROR 19 [django.request] [user 42] [ip 172.18.0.14] log.py:224 - Internal Server Error: /api/courseware/sequence/block-v1:SOS+CSE-10+2022_r1+type@sequential+block@b9aad4acdd1f48259c3dfd92fdc216c2
lms_1                        | Traceback (most recent call last):
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
lms_1                        |     response = get_response(request)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
lms_1                        |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
lms_1                        |   File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
lms_1                        |     return func(*args, **kwds)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
lms_1                        |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
lms_1                        |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
lms_1                        |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
lms_1                        |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./openedx/core/djangoapps/courseware_api/views.py", line 596, in get
lms_1                        |     sequence, _ = get_module_by_usage_id(
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./lms/djangoapps/courseware/module_render.py", line 1070, in get_module_by_usage_id
lms_1                        |     instance = get_module_for_descriptor(
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./lms/djangoapps/courseware/module_render.py", line 387, in get_module_for_descriptor
lms_1                        |     return get_module_for_descriptor_internal(
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./lms/djangoapps/courseware/module_render.py", line 806, in get_module_for_descriptor_internal
lms_1                        |     (system, student_data) = get_module_system_for_user(
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./lms/djangoapps/courseware/module_render.py", line 724, in get_module_system_for_user
lms_1                        |     field_data = DateLookupFieldData(descriptor._field_data, course_id, user)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/edx_when/field_data.py", line 51, in __init__
lms_1                        |     self._load_dates(course_id, user, use_cached=use_cached)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/edx_when/field_data.py", line 59, in _load_dates
lms_1                        |     for (location, field), date in api.get_dates_for_course(course_id, user, use_cached=use_cached).items():
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/edx_when/api.py", line 186, in get_dates_for_course
lms_1                        |     allow_relative_dates = _are_relative_dates_enabled(course_id)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/edx_when/api.py", line 70, in _are_relative_dates_enabled
lms_1                        |     return RELATIVE_DATES_FLAG.is_enabled(course_key)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./openedx/core/djangoapps/waffle_utils/__init__.py", line 122, in is_enabled
lms_1                        |     is_enabled_for_course = self._get_course_override_value(course_key)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./openedx/core/djangoapps/waffle_utils/__init__.py", line 78, in _get_course_override_value
lms_1                        |     course_override = WaffleFlagCourseOverrideModel.override_value(
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./openedx/core/lib/cache_utils.py", line 74, in decorator
lms_1                        |     result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/edx-platform/./openedx/core/djangoapps/waffle_utils/models.py", line 60, in override_value
lms_1                        |     effective = cls.objects.filter(waffle_flag=waffle_flag, course_id=course_id).order_by('-change_date').first()
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 674, in first
lms_1                        |     for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
lms_1                        |     self._fetch_all()
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
lms_1                        |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
lms_1                        |     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
lms_1                        |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
lms_1                        |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
lms_1                        |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 78, in _execute
lms_1                        |     self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
lms_1                        |   File "/openedx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 447, in validate_no_broken_transaction
lms_1                        |     raise TransactionManagementError(
lms_1                        | django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
lms_1                        | [pid: 19|app: 0|req: 28631/59539] 172.18.0.6 () {40 vars in 950 bytes} [Mon Jan  2 18:32:42 2023] GET /api/courseware/sequence/block-v1:SOS+CSE-10+2022_r1+type@sequential+block@b9aad4acdd1f48259c3dfd92fdc216c2 => generated 9585 bytes in 317 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 7 headers in 507 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

So what i did is following:

- i installed openedx with tutor ubuntu server.
- i made one seperate django-projcet and hosted in docker on same server.
- that seperate django-project is calling apis of openedx one of the api its calling is this `/api/courseware/sequence/{{block}}`.
- its calling this api very frequently.
- a lot of times it returns 200 response but sometimes it returns 500 internal error(from openedx side above shown is exception of that).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

UnitTest might be a reason for this kind of error. I suggest you look into this file `https://github.com/openedx/edx-platform/blob/open-release/olive.master/openedx/core/djangoapps/courseware_api/tests/test_views.py`